# Formatting the Output

Tags: python, time

[image]I have developed two algorithms to solve Problem 1 of Project Euler and I was trying to determine which one is faster. So I decided to import the time module, based on one of the suggestions on this site. The running time is about a 1000th of a second. But I'd still like to see at least 5 digits of the running time after the decimal place. So I have tried various formatting methods like round(), repr(), str() (I then slice the string), I have tried using the format modifiers, but nothing seems to work. I'll even attach my code for good measure. Please to suggest a modification that will help me!

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

check1 = True
x = 0
sum = 0

while check1:
    x += 3
    sum += x
    if x >=1000:
        check1 = False

y = 0

check2 = True

while check2:
    y += 5 
    if x % 3 != 0:
        sum += y
    if y >= 1000:
        check2 = False

print(sum)
print(round(time.time() - start.time , 5))
```

Just don't mind the indentation, something might've gone wrong while I copied the code! I have added a screenshot of the output too.

Comment: As the time module docs say, you should use the timeit module to time code, not the time module.

Comment: Yes, but it is meant to be used for very small snippets of code.

Comment: Meanwhile, for "I have tried using the format modifiers, but nothing seems to work", please show us _how_ you tried using the format modifiers, and explain what it did wrong. That's probably the right way to solve this, but we can't explain what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did.

Comment: code that runs in milliseconds counts as "small snippets". Really, you want to wrap this up in a function and call it lots of times with GC disabled and make sure to use a high-resolution clock and throw out the outliers from before the cache is warmed up and report the best time and so on, all of which `timeit` takes care of.

Comment: Meanwhile, type `help(round)`, or read the docs. The second argument is `ndigits`, the number of decimal digits to round to. And rounding to 0.5 decimal digits doesn't make much sense.

Comment: how does 5 become 0.5??

Comment: and yes, I have used format specifiers and not format modifiers, my bad. when I use something like print('The running time is %.5f',time.time()-start_time), the output is as follows: The running time is %.5f 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake in how to apply [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). Try this:

```
print('The running time is %.5f'%(time.time()-start_time))
```